# JAVA How to print an object with 3 integer values in it?

Tags: java

Let's say i created an object

```
class Data{

        int key;
        int frec;
        int id;

        public Data(int key, int frec, int id){
            this.key = key;
            this.frec = frec;
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
```

and then i created a list

```
  List<Data> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(new Data(2,3,0));

    System.out.println(list);
```

How to print the whole thing without this [com.company.Main$1Data@3feba861]? or better yet, how to for instance, only print out the frec? or id? and so on.
I couldnt find anything on google specifically about this, an object that contains 3 integers, and how to print / point one of the value of that object.

Comment: Override  `toString()` method with your desired behavior.

Comment: But how to do it with the int type?? i tried with overriding toString() method and it doesnt work, im assuming because different type?

Comment: @azurefrog i went there and tried exactly that, it didnt work, plus i have another extra  question as well. as to how to use pointer in my list, to point just one of three variable in my object.

Comment: If done correctly it works.  Obviously you are making a mistake.  Since you do not show us your `toString()` method it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @PM77-1 yeap! i had no understanding in how to modify the toString method!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your `Data` class to include a `toString()` method, like this:

```
public String toString() {
    return key + ", " + frec + ", " + id;
}
```

With that (or something similar to it), you could then do this:

```
Data data = new Data(1, 2, 3);
System.out.println(data);
```

and print output like this:

```
1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Thanks! i was confused on how to modify the method, that was my problem, now that worked!

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by overriding the toString() method of the Object class.